# PHP Accessing a multi-dimensional array from a name in a database field (eval vs variable variables)

Tags: php, variables

I have a situation where we have a database that is storing a lookup value as a string in the format of for example "output.acme.status".

The PHP script is reading some fairly complex JSON and pulling it into an array.

I need to grab the actual value of this named location. So for the above example of "output.acme.status" I would want to read $test['output']['acme']['status'].

I have tried various forms of eval and variable variables such as by the following type of pseudo code:

```
$desired_value = ${$database_field_name}
eval("\$database_field_name = \$database_field_name;");
```

These methods do not work. Using the example of eval at the PHP site seems perfect for my use case but the Example 1 with the coffee cup works great, but it does not work when I try to put in the multi-dimensional array.

I also changed the database field to contain the data in the format of $test['output']['acme']['status'], but without luck. My first thought was to allow the . notation format of output.acme.status and do an explode() on it to make the right structure. While this worked to output $test['output']['acme']['status'], it wouldn't actually evaluate that to give me the value.

In terms of security eval will not be taking input from raw users, but rather is being used internally by developers for test purposes.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure to be aware, but if you want "output.acme.status" to be "$test['output']['acme']['status']" i would split using "." separator and you will have your array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, you need first to split your string to get the differents parts in order to retrieve the array with a loop over the parts in the array.
This should do the trick :

```
function getValue(array $data, $path) {
    $parts = explode('.', $path);

    foreach ($parts as $key) {
        if (is_array($data) && isset($data[$key])) {
            $data =& $data[$key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This function does give me a PHP variable name in the format of $test['output']['acme']['status'], but what I now need is I need to be able to get the value of that variable. In this case the array $test should contain the value 0. So the value that "$test['output']['acme']['status']" should be the output, not the string "$test['output']['acme']['status']". Does that make sense?

Comment: It actually gives you the value :)

Comment: Ah yes you are exactly correct, thank you very much that worked perfectly once I removed all of the junk that I was playing with while trying to figure this out!